# How can we translate this statement into an input signal expression?

Tags: continuous-signals, control-systems

I want to make sure if I got this right, the following statement:

> if the operator
> enters a unity sloped linearly increasing input then the output must eventually track the
> input and be at most 0.1 cm away.

does it imply that the operator signals a function $x(t)=at+b$ for $a=1$ as an input?

Short summary: This is based on a project of designing a controller that allows the available robots to perform some packaging assessments. The operator here should control the arm of the robot.

Comment: Please provide a source for this statement. The wording is somewhat unusual and without context it's hard to tell what this is about.

Comment: Alright I will edit the question in a moment @Hilmar

Comment: Sorry, this still very confusing. "unity slope" implies that the input and the output have the same units. It can't be "position as a function of time" since the slope for this would have to be a velocity and cannot be unitless. So it could be either time as a function of time or position as a function of position, which honestly doesn't make much sense to me.